# onDestroy() callback of Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In my Android project, I have a normal `Service`:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(...){...}

  ...

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("MyApp","MyService onDestroy() is called!");
  }
}
```

In my `BroadcastReceiver` class, I stop `MyService` & do another task  :

```
public static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
       doAnotherTask();
   }
}
```

According to my log, `onDestroy()` of `MyService` is executed after `doAnotherTask()` is done.

How can I guarantee that `onDestory()` of `MyService` is executed before `doAnotherTask()` get called?

**P.S.:** I thought I could do something like:

```
boolean isStopped = context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
if(isStopped){
   doAnotherTask();
}
```

But it could be possible that there is no service has been started, which means `stopService(...)` does nothing. So, I can't rely on my above code.

Comment: if onDestroy is already destroying it then why to manually stop it? or if you have to stop it then why inside onDestroy()?

Comment: @Saqib, I am afraid you don't understand my question correctly. I only call stopService() after which I doAnotherTask(), that's it. System calls onDestroy() I didn't, I only stopService() . But I have something in onDestroy() callback.

Comment: have you tried a little delay between two tasks?

Comment: No, that's not the way I want.

Comment: try to stop your service within a method and then call your anotherTask method, and see if does the thing!

Comment: No, I tried already, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

How about sending a special intent to your broadcast receiver from the onDestroy() function? When your receiver gets it, then call doAnotherTask(). (I am assuming that you can't simply call doAnotherTask() from onDestroy() directly.)

Comment: That's not an ideal solution for me, since my broadcast receiver is used to receive system broadcasted intent. Besides, it is not possible to register another broadcast receiver inside an existing one.

Comment: But you can register your receiver for multiple actions, then inspect intent.getAction() in your onReceive() to determine whether to do your normal handling or your cleanup task. Without more information about what doAnotherTask() does, I can't really offer any better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

call startActivityForResult() .... and after you got the onActivityResult,.... call your method doAnotherTask()
i think that will do the job

Comment: I am not stopping my service in Activity, I am in a BroadcastReceiver class. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

send a broadcast in the service's onDestroy function and in it's observer do your after things

Answer (score 0):

The call to `stopService()` is asynchronous. You are basically telling Android that you want it to stop the `Service`. You have no control over when this actually occurs.

If you need to trigger something AFTER the `Service` is destroyed, then you send a broadcast `Intent` in `MyService.onDestroy()` and use that to trigger whatever you want to happen when the `Service` is destroyed.